# Add named namespace in Web.Config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, configuration

In my razor view I name a include namespace like this: `@using Resources = Project.Resources`. I want to include this namespace in every view. So I went to the Web.config of my views folder and added this:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="Project.Resources" />
    </namespace>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
</configuration>
```

Is there a way to add a name to this namespace? So I can type `@Resource.Label` in my views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i have investigated for about half an hour(actually much more time). you can find answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14101065/add-my-project-namespace-to-mvc-web-config), as danludwig mentioned. what you are doing is right, just save your project&solution, **and restart your visual studio**. i have tried it, works fine. hope help.

```
<add namespace="myNameSpace=Ioc.Model" />
```

Comment: Adding the namespace is not the problem. The problem is adding the namespace using a name in the web.config.

Comment: real sorry for taking no notice of this requirement. i have updated my post.

Comment: you may have to re-add the reference and restart visual studio, clean/rebuild and it works (vs2013)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but, 
There is also another way for adding a named namespace:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web.webPages.razor>
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="Projects = Project.Resources" />
        </namespace>
    </system.web.webPages.razor>
</configuration>
```

and as you mentioned, you can type @Resource.Label your views.