# Should we create separate partial views for listings that look almost similar?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

We are displaying list of cars in different view at different places on our website. For example:

1. https://jsfiddle.net/yxrveass/: Image and car details side by side.
2. https://jsfiddle.net/sa44zaz2/: Car details come just below the car image.

We have currently created two partial views for these i.e.

```
    @model IEnumerable<MVCDemo.Models.Cars>
    @foreach (var car in Model)
    {
      @Html.Partial("_Car1", car); //Partial view when Image and car details side by side.
    }

    @model IEnumerable<MVCDemo.Models.Cars>
    @foreach (var car in Model)
    {
      @Html.Partial("_Car2", car); //Partial view when Car details come just below the car image.
    }
```

The problem I see here is high maintenance cost. Tomorrow if we want to show one more field in UI i.e. city, we will have to do same changes at both _Car1 and _Car2 partial views.

Can we somehow combine the code of these two partial views so that we will have all car info in one cshtml file? (while keeping the subtle design differences as it is)

Comment: You can combine them (e.g. by using strategic `@if` statements in the .cshtml) but I wouldn't. Adding a field in two places is not "high cost" compared to the complexity of maintaining a view that "does it all."

Comment: There are too many options here, and while there are several best practice approaches to use for refactoring views, those will only loosely apply to a custom view like this and will vary greatly the more detail about the implementation is revealed. For something this small, just do what works, and if it gets out of hand, refactor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither of them should be partial views IMHO.  There should be single display template. The layout should change based on CSS not logic in the view.  I'm not a fan of using tables, unless you actually have data in a table (then it would look like excel, which yours does not).

```css
.car-titles{
  display: inline-block;
   font-weight: bold;
}

.car-details{
  display: inline-block;
}

.car-container-landscape .car-info{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.car-container{
  position: relative;
}

.car-container.car-container-landscape .car-picture,
.car-container.car-container-landscape .car-info {
  display: inline-block;

}
```

```html
<div>
<div class="car-container">
  <div class="car-picture">
    <img src="https://imgd.aeplcdn.com/370x208/cw/ucp/stockApiImg/1ZYKEUY_1104072_1_8199668.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="car-info">
    <div class="car-titles">
      <div>Name: </div>
      <div>Price: </div>
      <div>Fuel: </div>
    </div>
    <div class="car-details">
      <div>BMW</div>
      <div>100$</div>
      <div>Petrol</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Simply adding `car-container-landscape` changes the info's position.  So much simplier.

```
<div class="car-container @(Model.IsLandscape ? "car-container-landscape" : string.empty)">
```

Your model should not be an IEnumerable, it should be an actual model:

```
public class CarDetailsViewModel // or CarDetailsVM
{
  public IEnumerable<Cars> Cars { get; set; }
  public bool IsLandscape { get; set; }
}
```

[You can add the namespace to the `web.config`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14101065/add-my-project-namespace-to-mvc-web-config).

Additionally, there is no need to use a loop when using display templates because the Razor engine will loop automatically.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Cars)
```

Comment: Excellent advice.  Display and EditorTemplates are grossly under-utilized in MVC, and they are extremely powerful, model oriented, and logical.

Answer (score 0):

An option is to have a partial view for the image and a partial view for the information.  Then you have your current 2 partial views which just load the image and info partials into their respective places.

Solves the issue of adding additional info or if you wanted to make your image a scroll-able multi image viewer and having to update 2 different places.

Comment: A partial view for an image element is a waste. It may make sense to have a partial view for the information assuming that its layout doesn't change in the future, however, even *if* that were the case (where you have a partial for the information) you *still* retain two partial views for the two different layout and now additionally with your suggestion introduce a third partial view to support them.

Answer (score 0):

you can do some thing like this have one more partial for Details as shown...

Then you can have the flexibility later to extent in what ever way you need it.

case1:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    <img src="https://imgd.aeplcdn.com/370x208/cw/ucp/stockApiImg/1ZYKEUY_1104072_1_8199668.jpg" />
  </td>

  <td>
    // call partial view here with the particular record.
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>
    <img src="https://imgd.aeplcdn.com/370x208/cw/ucp/stockApiImg/1ZYKEUY_1104072_1_8199668.jpg" />
  </td>

  <td>
          // call partial view here with the particular record.
  </td>

</tr>

</table>




<table>
<tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <img src="https://imgd.aeplcdn.com/370x208/cw/ucp/S938430/2001-marutisuzukizen19962003vx-8120905.jpg" />
  </td>
</tr>

  <td>
          // call partial view here with the particular record.
  </td>


<tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    <img src="https://imgd.aeplcdn.com/370x208/cw/ucp/S938430/2001-marutisuzukizen19962003vx-8120905.jpg" />
  </td>
</tr>  
  <td>
           // call partial view here with the particular record. 
  </td>

</tr>

</table>
```

I prefer this if later you want to change any page you will have the flexibility.